# Google Vision Landmark recognition results based on geolocation and not image recognition

Tags: google-vision

I am submitting to google Vision API `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate` an image for landmark recognition with the following request.body:

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

...


{
requests: [{ 
     image: {content: await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(image.uri, {encoding: 
                                                         FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64})};
,
     features: {"type":"LANDMARK_DETECTION","maxResults":3}],
     imageContext: {"latLongRect":
                            {"minLatLng":{"latitude":-90,"longitude":-180},
                             "maxLatLng":{"latitude":90,"longitude":180}
                            },
                    "webDetectionParams":{"includeGeoResults":false}
}]
}
```

But, for example, for the picture of a church, I am getting back 3 landmarks: a bridge, a bar and another building. All of them are located near this church. All of them are not included in the picture and they look totally different (obviously).

It seems that Google Vision is somehow falling back to using the geolocation of the picture for landmark recognition (despite having set false for this option) and not using at all image processing. I got similar results with different landmarks.

Not sure what is the problem.